# Is it possible to change resolution in second pass for ffmpeg multipass encodes;x264 and x265?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, multimedia, hevc

I have been using the following commands for two pass encodes

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -c:v libx265 -x265-params pass=1:crf=22 -f mp4 /dev/null
ffmpeg -i <input> -c:v libx265 -x265-params pass=2 <output>
```

If i try changing resolution in second pass with vf scale

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -vf scale=720:-2 -c:v libx265 -x265-params pass=2 <output>
```

i get `

> [Error]CU-tree frame type 87 doesn't match actual frame type 0.

`

**EDIT 1:** x264 and x265 have been around for years did someone not find a solution/hack to having multiple output resolutions using stats from first pass at a different resolution, atleast bitrate distribution would look same i presume

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the same resolution, fps, and duration as used for the first pass. An encoder like x265 breaks up the frame into slices, which themselves consist of CTUs, which are of a certain pixel size. By changing resolution, the stats calculated in the first pass won't match up with the partitioning in the 2nd pass.

Comment: x264 and x265 have been around for years did someone not find a solution/hack to having multiple output resolutions using stats from first pass at a different resolution, atleast bitrate distribution would look same i presume.

Comment: Bitrate distribution isn't the controlling factor. Take an image of a soccer ball in the top-left corner of the frame. At 640x360, the 64x64 block at the top-left will contain a bit of the background and bit of the arc of the ball. During first-pass, the encoder will produce stats based on this scenario and detail. If you perform 2nd-pass on a 1080p version, the top-left CTU of 64x64 will contain different image data e.g. only the background.